# Rendering function on modal dialog pop up, Using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

How to render a function while opening the modal dialog in angularJS. Currently what I have done is call the function in window resize event but its not working. (and its working when I resize the browser window but I need that function to be called immediately after modal dialog pop up)

**CODE:**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   setup();
});
```

Comment: There's no angularjs in your code at all. It's JQuery. If your'e working with angular, Jquery should be used as a last resort. There are numerous modals available for Angular.

Answer (score 0):

For resizing a Pop-up automatically, You need to handle it using either a special directive or need to perform some DOM manipulation using jQuery.

Please check below references:

[ngResize Directive](https://github.com/danmasta/ngResize)